# Subsetting DataFrame using ix in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, subset

I am trying to learn how subsetting works in pandas DataFrame. I made a random dataframe as below.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1234)
X = pd.DataFrame({'var1' : np.random.randint(1,6,5), 'var2' : np.random.randint(6,11,5), 
                  'var3': np.random.randint(11,16,5)})
X = X.reindex(np.random.permutation(X.index))
X.iloc[[0,2], 1] = None
```

X returns,

```
   var1  var2  var3
0     3   NaN    11
4     3     9    13
3     2   NaN    14
2     5     9    12
1     2     7    13
```

pandas method `.loc` is strictly label based and `.iloc` is for integer positions. `.ix` can be used to combine position based index and labels.

However, in the above example, the row indices are integers, and `.ix` understands them as row indices not positions. Suppose that I want to retrieve the first two rows of 'var2'. In R, `X[1:2, 'var2']` would give the answer. In Python, `X.ix[[0,1], 'var2']` returns `NaN 7` rather than `NaN 9`.

The question is "Is there a simple way to let `.ix` know the indices are position based?"

I've found some solutions for this but they are not simple and intuitive in some cases.

For example, by using `_slice()` as below, I could get the result I wanted.

```
>>> X._slice(slice(0, 2), 0)._slice(slice(1,2),1)
   var2
0   NaN
4     9
```

When the row indices are not integers, there's no problem.

```
>>> X.index = list('ABCED')
>>> X.ix[[0,1], 'var2']
A   NaN
B     9
Name: var2, dtype: float64
```

Comment: But you have a method for indexing using integer location so why not just use `iloc` to avoid the ambiguous indexing?

Comment: @EdChum Yes, `X.iloc[[0,1],1]` returns the subset, but there is a case that you only know the attribute name 'var2'.

Comment: @EdChum Maybe you're right. I couldn't think of any case that I only know the attribute names. I guess I went too far away.

Comment: You could use `X['var2'].iloc[[0,1]]`.

Comment: @ubutbu I knew it must be that simple. That's the answer. I spent 30+ mins for this. Ah~

Comment: @NeoJi: `X['var2'].iloc[[0,1]]` is safe for both access and assignments, but be careful if you use this for assignments, since does not generalize to the case of assignments with multiple columns. For example, `X[['var2', 'var3']].iloc[[0,1]] = ...`  generates a **copy** of a sub-DataFrame of `X` so assignment to this sub-DataFrame does not modify `X`. See the docs on ["Why assignments using chained indexing fails"](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#why-does-the-assignment-when-using-chained-indexing-fail).

Comment: @unutbu Thanks. Would you post an answer with the solution in your comments? My question is resolved, and I don't know how to make your comment to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `X['var2'].iloc[[0,1]]`:

```
In [280]: X['var2'].iloc[[0,1]]
Out[280]: 
0   NaN
4     9
Name: var2, dtype: float64
```

---

Since `X['var2']` is a **view** of `X`, `X['var2'].iloc[[0,1]]` is safe for both
access and assignments. But be careful if you use this "chained indexing"
pattern (such as the index-by-column-then-index-by-`iloc` pattern used here) for assignments, since it does not
generalize to the case of assignments with multiple columns.

For example, `X[['var2', 'var3']].iloc[[0,1]] = ...` generates a **copy** of a
sub-DataFrame of X so assignment to this sub-DataFrame does not modify `X`. 
See the docs on ["Why assignments using chained indexing
fails"](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#why-does-the-assignment-when-using-chained-indexing-fail) for more explanation.

To be concrete and to show why this view-vs-copy distinction is important: If you have this warning turned on:

```
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = 'warn'
```

then this assign raises a `SettingWithCopyWarning` warning:

```
In [252]: X[['var2', 'var3']].iloc[[0,1]] = 100
SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a
DataFrame
See the the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  self._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value)
```

and the assignment fails to modify `X`. Eek!

```
In [281]: X
Out[281]: 
   var1  var2  var3
0     3   NaN    11
4     3     9    13
3     2   NaN    14
2     5     9    12
1     2     7    13
```

---

To get around this problem, when you want an assignment to affect `X`, you must
assign to a **single indexer** (e.g. `X.iloc = ...` or `X.loc = ...` or `X.ix = ...`) -- that is, *without chained indexing*.

In this case, you could use

```
In [265]: X.iloc[[0,1], X.columns.get_indexer_for(['var2', 'var3'])] = 100

In [266]: X
Out[266]: 
   var1  var2  var3
0     3   100   100
4     3   100   100
3     2   NaN    14
2     5     9    12
1     2     7    13
```

but I wonder if there is a better way, since this is not terribly pretty.